# Create a record from Visualforce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a custom object with 5 Questions and field Api Names are 
Q1__c, Q2__c, Q3__c, Q4__c, Q5__c

**Requirement :**

This is a Question answer from with question having more than 40 characters so i am doing in the visualforce page

Page:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Phone_Screen__c" extensions="PhoneScreenController">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:actionFunction name="sendvalues" action="{!process}" reRender="renderme">
            <apex:param assignTo="{!option}" name="value1" value="" />
        </apex:actionFunction>

        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Phone_Screen__c.Type__c}" styleClass="type" onchange="callmethod()" /> 
                <!--This is a custom picklist field-->
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>

        <apex:pageBlock id="renderme">
            <apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!panel1}"> 
                <apex:variable var="count" value="{!0}"/>
                <apex:repeat value="{!questions}" var="i">
                    <span id="question{!count}">{!questions[count].Question__c}</span>
                    <textarea id="answer{!count}"></textarea>
                    <apex:variable var="count" value="{!count + 1}"/>
                </apex:repeat>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function callmethod(){
            sendvalues(document.getElementsByClassName('type')[0].value);
        }
    </script>

</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class PhoneScreenController {

    public Boolean panel1{get; set;}
    public String option{get;set;}

    public PhoneScreenController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        panel1 = false;
    }

    public pageReference process(){
        if(option == 'Value1') {
            panel1 = true; 
        }
        return null;
    }

    public List<Questions__c> getquestions(){
        List<Questions__c> mc = Questions__c.getAll().values();
        return mc;
    }

}
```

**Issue:**
I am trying to get the answer for a particular question in textarea and I am looking to save this value to the corresponding question while creating the record. How can I map this value to that question while creating the record as questions come from custom settings and the number of questions can keep changing.

Right now I created a custom setting which has the following fields:
- apiname__c : to store the field apiname
- question__c: for the question

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper class to hold questions and answers and in this `getquestions()` method return the List of Wrapper class object. It will help you to manipulate and save the data.